# Script del tipo bash que testee el estado de la red (Unix)

Tags: bash, dns, ip

Necesito crear un script que devuelva una información concreta sobre la red:

- La IP y la mascara del host.
- La IP de el ruter por defecto.
- La IP de el servidor DNS de mi red.

Y que devuelva los resultados (diga si hay conexión) con tiempos de respuesta al:

- Comprobar la conectividad con el ruter.
- Comprobar la conectividad con el servidor DNS de mi red.
- Comprobar la conectividad con un servidor externo.

Comment: ¿Sobre que sistema operativo y distribución estás tratando de hacer el script? ¿Tienes algo empezado?

Comment: Unix, ubuntu. He intentado hacerlo usando el comando ifconfig y sus opciones pero solo he conseguido la información del primer punto.

Comment: Nótese que este sitio no es un lugar donde pedir que se le haga el trabajo a uno, sino donde exponer dudas concretas. Por ello, voto para cerrar la pregunta por ser demasiado amplia.

Comment: Lectura obligatoria: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No estoy seguro si de esta manera te sirve pero hay un comando que quizás te sirva:

**ip addr show**

El cual te muestra un cuadro con información básica. Para ser mas especifico podrías probar con los siguientes.

Para la IP Address :

```
ip addr show |grep -w inet |grep -v 127.0.0.1|awk '{ print $2}'| cut -d "/" -f 1
```

Para la netmask :

```
ifconfig | grep -w inet |grep -v 127.0.0.1| awk '{print $4}' | cut -d ":" -f 2
```

Para el DNS :

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

Para el router podria ser :

```
$ route -n
```

Para comprobar conexiones en caso de que quieras realizar un script tendrías que al menos mostrar si has intentado alguno.

Para comprobar la conexion de una ip puedes realizar con esta estructura:

```
if ping -c 1 some_ip_here &> /dev/null
then
  echo 1
else
  echo 0
fi
```

Te lo puede devolver en codigo de numeros donde 0 es reachable y el 2 unreachable.

Para el check del DNS saca un script parecido a un nslookup.

```
#!/bin/bash

resolvedIP=$(nslookup "$1" | awk -F':' '/^Address: / { matched = 1 } matched { print $2}' | xargs)

# Comprobar si tiene una IP valida

[[ -z "$resolvedIP" ]] && echo "$1" lookup failure || echo "$1" resolved to "$resolvedIP"
```

O un dig and test:

```
[ "$(dig +short -t srv _ldap._tutcp.ejemplo.es.)" ] && echo "Llegamos"
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Comment: Mas o menos era la que necesitaba. Solo tengo que tocarlo un poco para filtrar los output y que sea mas especifico. Muchas gracias!

Comment: @Chusito, si te ha servido y crees que la respuesta es válida por favor considera aceptar la respuesta haciendo clic en el botón de aceptar que hay debajo del contador de votos de la respuesta.